# Passing Arguments to a Method in EventHandler

Tags: c#, asp.net, button, event-handling, arguments

This question has been asked many times but the solution is not working for some reason.

I am dynamically creating a Button and assigning an EventHandler to it.

```
protected void Page_Load (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button b = new Button();
    b.Click += new EventHandler(Method);
}

protected void Method (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //Do work here
}
```

I needed to pass an argument so the most simple way I thought of was this:

```
b.Click += new EventHandler(Method(sender, e, "name"));

protected void Method (object sender, EventArgs e, String name)
{
   //Do work here
}
```

> **Error:** Method name expected

So after checking the questions here, I found the same solution in almost every question.

```
b.Click += new EventHandler((sender, e) => Method(sender, e, "name"));
```

> **Error:** A local variable named "sender" cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to "sender", which is
>   already used in a 'parent or current' scope to denote something else.

So I changed to the following:

```
b.Click += new EventHandler((sender1, e1) => Method(sender1, e1, "name"));
```

And the error from Visual Studio was gone, but upon running the webpage, I received this error:

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be a
>   non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

What's the problem here I'm really lost.

Comment: Is the `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` error thrown on that EventHandler line or elsewhere?

Comment: Perhaps there's some a reference to the code with the ArgumentOutOfRangeException. You should show it here.

Comment: @keyboardP Yes exactly on the EventHandler line.

Comment: In the case of ASP this problem is a bit...special.  You need to re-create the controls on each post-back, and re-wire up the event handlers.  In doing so the object that you're closing over isn't being maintained between postbacks.  Ideally you'd just not add buttons dynamically; it's almost certainly possible and most likely desirable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your declaration of adding Eventhandler to custom method is correct. The source of error is something else. Look at the **CallStack** when you're getting this exception and see what is the actual source of your error.

Comment: Thanks, problem was completely something else, I feel so stupid.

Answer (score 0):

If you subscribe to `Button.Click` event, you have no much choice, as your subscript *must* follow relative delegate pattern. In other words, you can not add our custom parameters to even handler, as signature of your handler *must* match exactly the delegate type defined on the event you listen to.

So, to pass parameter:

- or define a global state variable, and read it from the same event handler
- or define some custom event handler, with some custom event argument

Comment: I am trying to save the state , but cant find the appropriate variable to store it. Some say, the type of variable should be  Action, while some say it to be Func.

      ShapeNodeEventArgs shapeNodeArgs = new ShapeNodeEventArgs(shapeHit.Tag as DeviceMap);
    
      mnuShapeLogicalGrid.Click += (s, ev) => { displayDeviceLogicalData(sender, shapeNodeArgs);};
    
      frmDisplay.ContextMenuStrip = ctxtGridStrip ;

This has been discussed on SO , but I cant understand the variable type yet . 
All comments are welcome.